# How to bundle dependencies in Gradle for multiple applications

Tags: gradle

I'd like to somehow enable shared dependency management between different applications using Gradle and have created a hierarchy of 'bundles' essentially packaging Java, Spring, Groovy and various test artifacts.

The root of the 'bundling' consists of config as below:

```
ext {

    // Spring-specific
    springVersion           = '4.1.7.RELEASE'
    springCore              = "org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}"
    springContext           = "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
    springBeans             = "org.springframework:spring-beans:${springVersion}"
    springBase              = [springCore, springContext, springBeans]

    ... and more Spring

    // Miscellaneous
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    groovy = 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
    servlet = 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    ... and more
}

subprojects {

    // Enabling Groovy, Wrapper

}
```

With a 'Spring bundle' configured as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
        groovy,
        springBase,
    )
}
```

JAR artifacts like my common-spring then depend on the above 'bundle' - and other projects depend on common-spring.

Building locally using Gradle's Maven plugin, this works when I also install the 'bundles' and 'common' to my local Maven repository. However, I am unsure if this is the way I'm 'supposed' to do it in Gradle.

An alternative (and perhaps more correct?) approach could be publishing to Artifactory and resolving artifacts from there, thus (hopefully?) not using any Maven-y stuff at all.

Or is there a completely different and simpler way I could centralize which versions I use of various third-party artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a good way to share dependencies and in fact Gradle's build uses this same technique.

One difference is that they create a single map to store all of the bundles and wrap them all in a list.

```
ext.libs = [:]
libs.springCore = ["org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}",]
...
```

Comment: But what if I would like to share the same dependencies among totally unrelated projects? Gradle does not seem to have something equivalent to Mavens parent POM.